# Huge difference in Google Analytics if I use segments or not

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I am using Google Analytics for basic reporting and I stumble upon a very unclear result that I cant explain. I am viewing my pageviews using /Behaviour/SiteContent/All pages

I started looking at all sessions only (the default information displayed). This gave me information such as, for week from Oct 5 to Oct 11, **17,351** page views.

Then I added a segment for Direct traffic, to see how my direct traffic was doing, then in the diagram, the "all sessions" segment is suddenly boosted to **25,092** page views.

The difference beetween **17k** and **25k** is huge! Even if GA use subset and extrapolation, I would expect results to be consistant.

Any thing obvious that I am missing?
Any input would be highly appreciated.

[see reports here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u70dytstxd0lw2v/overflowanalytics.png?dl=0)

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is (other) category in yours report. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009671

Result of that aggregation is that "all session" doesn't mean exactly 100% of traffic (in my report it's 76% in 2 week time period).

Try to exclude url params to minify number of pages or shorten time period (I know you've selected only one week and probably you don't want to analyze day by day).